# How to Add a File to the SSIS Project Miscellaneous Folder

Tags: ssis, bids

I'm using BIDS2008 and I want to add a file to the Miscellaneous folder of my SSIS project.

I have tried:

1. to drag-and-drop a file to the folder icon in Solution Explorer -
   not allowed
2. to right-click the folder icon - return 0 menu options
3. to add-item from the project icon in Solution Explorer - didn't see
   anything helpful there
4. to create the folder by hand, add a dummy text file,
   close-reopen-rebuild solution - no success of any kind

This must be something really simple, but I have no idea what.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Right click on the Project Click `ADD`->`Exisiting Item`. Now you can point to any files in the dialogue box  which does not have extension such as `dtsx` or `config` .Selecting these files will automatically place them in `Miscellaneous folder`