# Include SQL scripts in SSIS package?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a few SQL scripts (e.g. create tables) that I would like to include in my SSIS project for the sake of tidiness and inclusion in the Git repository.  They aren't used by the package itself.

Is there a good place for them (perhaps the `Miscellaneous` folder) ?  Are there any issues with including them in the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use this approach all the time, storing CREATE TABLE and other set-up scripts in the Misc folder.   We've never had a problem with this approach.

Comment: How do you *actually* add a `.SQL` file to the folder?  Drag and drop doesn't work and I can't seem to locate the actual folder within the project itself.

Comment: Found the answer: [How to Add a File to the SSIS Project Miscellaneous Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193169/how-to-add-a-file-to-the-ssis-project-miscellaneous-folder)

Answer (score 1):

Another option that I have often used to store all setup tasks is to place them all in an Execute SQL Task and then right-click on it an select disable. That way it doesn't effect the package when running, but should you need to recreate the database/tables it becomes as simple as:

1. Right-click and select Enable
2. Right-click and select Execute Task
3. Right-click and select Disable