# SSIS Project will not show a new folder added

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I created a folder called BatchFiles in TFS for an SSIS project, but the folder will not show in the solution explorer. I've also noticed that .dtproj file will not show, even if I click the "Show All Files" button on top. Is there any way to show the new folder I created in solution explorer? Also will the .dtproj file always be hidden?

[image]

Add new item directly to the project does this:
[image]

Adding an existing item option automatically dumped it in Miscellaneous Folder, that looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You just put it in a directory, you did not add it to the project yet.  The .dtproj file is the projectname you have blacked out (thats the project file, or representation of it that holds all the project settings and whats included in them).

Comment: If I try to add an item directly to the project in solution explorer it adds it to the folder Miscellaneous, I don't get an option to add a custom folder to the project through Solution Explorer.

Comment: I dont think you can in SSIS projects.

Comment: Hi  @MilesMorales  Did the `.dtproj` file located in BatchFiles folder at present now? Could you add a screenshot for this "If I try to add an item directly to the project in solution explorer it adds it to the folder Miscellaneous, I don't get an option to add a custom folder to the project through Solution Explorer." When you directly add item in the visual studio?

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu-MSFT I added pictures of how it appears when I try to "Add Item" or "Add Existing Item" in VS through solution explorer, directly to the project, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like those existing items are not being considered as project files but as misc files when being opened from solution explorer.

This seems to be an expected behavior

> Any files in the dialogue box which does not have extension such as
>   dtsx or config .Selecting these files will automatically place them in
>   Miscellaneous folder

[How to Add a File to the SSIS Project Miscellaneous Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193169/how-to-add-a-file-to-the-ssis-project-miscellaneous-folder)

---

If the file exists on disk (physically in the folder) but does not show in the solution then it is likely that the file was checked in, but the modification to the solution was not. And for BatchFiles folder, you just add them in the source control explorer. That's why there are not the in the solution explorer.

Also will the .dtproj file always be hidden?

Seems to be so. I have also reproduced and got the same behavior like this. Sorry, not very familiar with SSIS project. But according to some tutorials in google such as this
Blog : [Building your SSIS project in Azure DevOps](http://bifuture.blogspot.com/2018/07/devops-building-your-ssis-project-in.html) It not appears, but we also able to build it through Azure DevOps.

Comment: That's so odd considering in other project types I'm able to add named folders and have them show in solution explorer. Seems like the SSIS project type forces you to use a "Miscellaneous" Folder and doesn't allow the aforementioned folder customization right?